# Replace all hex encodings in a python string with equivalent ascii values

Tags: regex, python-2.7, replace

I have a string that contains hex values inside brackets. I need to find all those strings and replace them with the decoded values.

**Example input**: `MainDir[0x2f]SubDir[0x2f]Hello[0x2d]world[0x2e]txt`

**Desired output:** `MainDir/SubDir/Hello-world.txt`

While I was posting this question I tried few options and came up with one possible answer and thought to post it for others. Please feel free to post if you have better options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short solution:

```
import re
s = "MainDir[0x2f]SubDir[0x2f]Hello[0x2d]world[0x2e]txt"
result = re.sub(r'\[0x[0-9a-f]{2}\]', lambda m: chr(int(m.group()[1:-1], 16)), s)

print(result)   # MainDir/SubDir/Hello-world.txt
```

---

`\[0x[0-9a-f]{2}\]` - matches hex string

Comment: Thanks and +1. Yes, lambda does shorten the code and I like the explicit check for 2 char hex string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up doing it:

```
def replHexWithascii(matchobj):
    #matchobj.group(0) contains [0xdd]
    #matchobj.group(0)[1:-1] gives strips off [ and ] and returns 0xdd
    #int(hexstring, 16) converts the hexstring '0x2f' to 47
    #chr(i) returns equivalent ascii
    hexstring = matchobj.group(0)[1:-1]
    return chr(int(hexstring, 16))

re.sub(r"\[.*?\]", replHexWithascii,"MainDir[0x2f]SubDir[0x2f]Hello[0x2d]world[0x2e]txt")
```

output:`'MainDir/SubDir/Hello-world.txt'`

References: [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)